# SQL Server Data Tools Explore Data error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql, provider

I am reading a step-by-step book to learn more about SQL Server Analysis Services. I am creating a dimension for an AdventureWorks data source. In the Design Diagram pane, I right click on the header of a table and then I click 'Explore Data'. I am given this error: `The 'SQLNCLI10.1' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

From searching online it sounds like I have to find out how to change my provider to'SQLNCLI11', or 11.1, in some connection string, but I don’t know how to find this connection string.

I have SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2010 Shell(SQL Server Data Tools), and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Install the SQL Server Native Client. Scroll down and find it http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=29065 Although native client 10 is SQL Server 2008 so you might need to get it from the 2008 feature pack page. I don't know if 2012's has all the previous versions in it.

Comment: Thanks @ta.speotis, I just tried to install the [2012 native client](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409) and got this error: `Installation of SQL Server 2012 Native Client failed because a higher version exists on the machine.` If I am using SQL Server 2012 should I really install the 2008 client to work for client 10? Shouldn't I just update the solution to use client 11? How do I do that?